# What happens to cursors to MediaStore when the underlying database gets updated?

Tags: android, cursor, mediastore

In my app (a small mp3-player for an university project) I'm doing query `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`. Currently, I'm caching the songs to an array, but I'm thinking of moving it over to just using the `Cursor` object.

I can see a few problems:

1. The underlying database can get updated (the Android device detected a song getting added or removed)
2. A song gets removed without the database getting updated.

For the first point:

- what happens to the cursor when the database gets updated?
- How can I detect when MediaStore gets updated?

For the second point:

- Is the only thing I can do to detect this to try to access the resource and see whether it fails?